# How to override global meta tags in a specific template in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, amp-html

I am not sure if this is possible but here it comes.

I have a nuxt.config.js such as (I have changed some information such as content and href attributes for privacy):

```js
head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'de-DE'
    },
    title: 'My Title',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'My Content.' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/images/icons/favicon.png' },
      { rel: 'preload', as: 'style', onload: "this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'", href: 'mycss' },
      { rel: 'preload', as: 'style', onload: "this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'", href: 'mycss' },
      { rel: 'dns-prefetch', href: 'https://www.google-analytics.com' }
    ]
  }
```

As you can see I have two preload link tags which includes onload. I am doing some AMP pages for SEO and AMP gives an error for onload.

> The attribute 'onload' may not appear in tag 'link rel=preload

So I want to override those link tags only in my AMP pages. What I have tried is head() function for my AMP pages to override global settings however it didn't override and actually added new links.

```js
export default {
  head () {
    return {
       link: [
         // my links
      ]
    }
    
  }
}
```

I have checked the documentation and looked a few questions here but couldn't find a solution. Is there any way that I can achieve this ?

PS: I want to keep those 2 links in my global because there are lots of pages that uses it.

Comment: Btw as a side note, I've heard that AMP will maybe tend to disappear. Maybe give it a read and see if it's worth the hassle or if you'll need to remove it in some time.

Comment: @kissu Thank you for this information. As a developer, I am just trying to make the work done ! But noted. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo):

> To avoid any duplication when used in child components, please give a unique identifier with the hid key to the meta description. This way vue-meta will know that it has to overwrite the default tag.

So try to add an `hid` attribute to your meta tags to identify them and be able to override them with sub components.

```js
// nuxt.config.js
head: {
    link: [
      { hid: 'my-stylesheet', rel: 'preload', as: 'style', href: 'mycss' },
    ]
  }
```

```js
// page/amp.vue
head: {
    link: [
      { hid: 'my-stylesheet', rel: 'preload', as: 'style', href: 'overridedHref' },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Well this was the thing that I have tried to do but I didn't add hid to my config file that is why it didn't work. Now I got it and it works ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had as well some issue, with head().

In dev mode I was not seeing any meta data rendered, but when I run `nuxtgenereate static` (which was my goal anyway) the links were there.

I am not sure, if you wanna go static, but I would try it, to see if it is there or check, what happens if you actually build the app.